# How do you modify wordpress css for posts?

Tags: html, wordpress, css

So, Im using wordpress.com to run my blog. I have paid for the upgrade with custom css. Now I want to change the formatting of posts that are on the front page. Ive been using the "inspect element" on Chrome, simular to Firebug, to see what class everything has and changing the CSS.

Its been pretty easy other than the posts. Each post, apparently has its own class.

my latest post is of class="post-190"

However, the post before it is class="post-188"
 etc...
How do you write a CSS to include all of the post-##

Comment: show us template. In some templates class is the same `class="post"` or something. In some other templates they are like you described but post div have child divs with unique classes which construct the post div and you might work with them. All of this if you dont want to use selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these attribute selectors

> [class|=post]
> an element whose "class" attribute has a hyphen-separated list of values beginning (from the left) with "post"
>
> [class^=post]
> an element whose "class" attribute value begins exactly with the string "post"

[Source](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

From the basic `TwentyEleven Wordpress theme` let me suppose that you want to add border to this post, the structure of this class is forming from the `wp-includes/post-template.php` file.

This method is creating the class for this post -- `get_post_class()`

[image]

And then add styling to my `content-aside.php` page in the template, i hope this is what you are looking for, ley me know if u have an issue.